# Html.ActionLink() in ASP.NET MVC4 is not Rendering Correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid-asp.net

Un Expected result while rendering @Html.ActionLink in the browser. Below are the code i written in jqGrid for displaying link column.

```
{ name: 'Restart',
                         formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                             var x = '@Html.ActionLink( "Restart", "Dashboard", new { requestId ="myId"  }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure to Restart?');" })';
                             return x.replace("myId",rowObject[8]);
                         }, align: 'left', width: 100
                     }
```

After rendering in the browser it displayed like this

```
<a href="/DashBoard/Dashboard?requestId=2362e13b-e4fc-4140-b7ad-1bd0e82b6bde" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to Restart?');">Restart</a>
```

When I replace @Html.ActionLink( "Restart", "Restart") in the above code.It displays correctly like this.

```
 <a href="/Dashboard/Restart?requestId=2362e13b-e4fc-4140-b7ad-1bd0e82b6bde" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to Restart?');">Restart</a>
```

Why ASP.NET MVC4 produce Un Expected result? Is there any fix for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't consider this behaviour as unexpected. You are using following overload of [LinkExtensions.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

So the second parameter is action name and controller name defaults to current controller.

Comment: It's Not an Unexpected behavior.it's the problem of parameter i passing

Answer (score 0):

its because you need to check the parameters of Html.ActionLink

I assume you are in the DashBoardController

The first para is the string you want displayed in the link
The second is the parameter
The third is the controller

and so on...

You may want to look at what you and do with the Url.Action() to make this code a bit neater